# Value prints correctly in function, but when returned is None

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, return

I am just trying to brush up on my python, so I am sure I made a basic mistake here. My code is just a toy app that finds the largest item in a circularly-sorted array.

Here is my code:

```
def listIsSorted(l):
    if l[0] < l[-1]:
        return 1
    return 0

def findLargest(l):
    listLength = len(l)
    if(listLength == 1):
        return l[0]
    if(listLength == 2):
        if(l[0] > l[1]):
            print("OMG I Found it: " + str(l[0]))
            return l[0]
        return l[1]

    halfway = int(listLength/2)
    firsthalf = l[:int(halfway)]
    secondhalf = l[int(halfway):]
    if(listIsSorted(firsthalf) and listIsSorted(secondhalf)):
        return max(l[halfway - 1], l[-1])
    elif (listIsSorted(firsthalf)):
        findLargest(secondhalf)
    else:
        findLargest(firsthalf)

l4 = [5,1,2,3]
print(findLargest(l4))
```

and this outputs the following:

```
OMG I Found it: 5
None
```

My question is: Why is it being returned as type `None`, when it just printed as 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it have to be modified this way since you forgot to return results of recursion call:

```
def findLargest(l):
    listLength = len(l)
    if listLength == 1:
        return l[0]
    if listLength == 2:
        if l[0] > l[1]:
            print "OMG I Found it: {0}".format(l[0])
            return l[0]
        return l[1]

    halfway = int(listLength/2)
    firsthalf = l[:int(halfway)]
    secondhalf = l[int(halfway):]
    if listIsSorted(firsthalf) and listIsSorted(secondhalf):
        return max(l[halfway - 1], l[-1])
    elif listIsSorted(firsthalf):
        return findLargest(secondhalf)
    else:
        return findLargest(firsthalf)
```

Comment: Oh man. Good catch. Appreciate the second pair of eyes. Have a good one!